# HTML / CSS : pie chart pixel error on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I wanted to develop a circular progress bar, so i started by creating a pie chart with html / css and got this code working fine. I just have a little issue of rendering happened some time. Here is what I got on my dev website (img) and I pasted my code too. The result here is perfect, and it's strange because I'm using the same browser to check the result. The result on Firefox is perfect for both (dev website and stack result).
[image: result on my website]

I "fixed" the issue by removing "overflow: hidden" applied to the .half-left element when the pie chart has a value greater than 50%, but I can't animate it if it's moving from 25% to 75% for example

```css
.radial-progress {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #d6dadc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden
}

.radial-progress .half-right,
.radial-progress .half-left {
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}

.radial-progress .half-right .fill,
.radial-progress .half-left .fill {
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  right: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  background-color: rebeccapurple
}
```

```html
<div class="radial-progress" ng-reflect-set-value="99">

  <div class="half-right">
    <div class="fill" style="transform: rotate(112deg);"></div>
    <div class="fill" style="transform: rotate(224deg);"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-left rotated" style="transform: rotate(112deg);">
    <div class="fill" style="transform: rotate(112deg);"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: me also not getting your issue

Comment: I'm not getting this every time, I noticed that when I added `position: fixed; top: 0` the issue is not showing, but with `position: fixed; right: 0` it is. So it depends on where the element is displayed, I think it's a browser rendering issue and maybe there is a css fix or whatever to fix that issue